# ¿como extraer filas de campo de tabla sql en String con C#?

Tags: c#, sql-server, string, lista

Buen dia, quisiera saber como puedo extraer todas las filas de un determinado campo en variables (String) utilizando C#.

Por ejemplo:

```
Campo = Usuario
```

filas de dicho campo :

```
Juan   
Ana 
Jose
```

ponerlos en variables de esta forma:

```
String nombre1 --> Juan  
String nombre2 --> Ana   
String nombre3 --> Jose
```

PD: Utilizo sqlserver

PD2: tengo los siguientes campos : `Id_User` , `Usuario` y `Pass`

Adjunto codigo actual:

```
conexion.Open();

        SqlCommand cmd = conexion.CreateCommand();
        SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        reader.Read();
        string nombre = reader.GetString(1);

        int cant = nombre.Count();



conexion.Close();
```

Comment: No esta clara tu pregunta. Si te entiendo bien, simplemente en lugar de variables individuales, usar un array `string[] nombres` y ve añadiendo los campos de la base de datos en un bucle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La respuesta rápida es: en tiempo de compilación NO puedes crear variables con esa clase de nombres.

Lo que sí puedes hacer es crear una colección de `string`s en donde puedas explorar los nombres así:

```
nombres[1]
```

Considera que hacerlo sobre una variable de tipo `string[]` implica que conoces previamente (de alguna manera) su tamaño final. De no ser así, considera creando una `List<string>` a la que le puedes agregar *n* cantidad de elementos.

```
DataTable dt;
using (SqlConnection DBCon = new SqlConnection("..."))
{
    using (SqlCommand cmnd = new SqlCommand("SELECT ...", DBCon))
    {
        DBCon.Open();
        using (SqlDataReader reader = cmnd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            dt = new DataTable();
            if (reader.HasRows)
            {
                SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmnd);
                reader.Dispose();
                da.Fill(dt);
            }
        }
    }
}

List<string> nombres = new List<string>();
foreach(DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
{
    nombres.Add(dr["Usuario"].ToString());
}
```

Para recorrerlo, basta con un ciclo:

```
for(int x = 0; x < nombres.Lenght; x++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(nombres[x]);
}
```